# Suggested edit on answer with high votes

Tags: discussion, suggested-edits

In my review queues, the following suggested edit came up:

https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/22210409

The edit is on an accepted answer with net 124 votes (+125, -1). The original is very light on the details, providing an outdated link and a one-line fix.

To me, the existing answer is great in that it is succint and straight to the point, which is probably why it has been upvoted so much.

The suggested edit also looks great though, in that it gives reasoning as to why the one-liner will work, and gives some background into the issue.

I'm inclined to allow the edit, but I can see a case for both rejecting the edit and accepting it. Not sure if Meta is the right place to ask, but I'm interested in feedback as to what is the correct decision when reviewing.

Comment: Messing with that kind of magic is dangerous, yes.  But there's something else going on, the answer got only two helpful votes in the year after it was posted.  It now gets voted on almost every day, starting around Oct 18 of last year.  Seems they screwed up the installer again, the answer was a lucky match.  Not the kind of luck any victim ought to be thrilled about, this DLL Hell problem today is very, very different from the one in 2010.  Annotating it to give some background (missing in the linked web page) seems highly appropriate.

Answer (score 17):

I think the edit is appropriate to be approved because it meets the [criteria](https://stackoverflow.com/help/editing) of "To add related resources.." in this case from the hyperlink in the answer. Given that link could break at any point in time, including the additional context on SO is appropriate.

Comment: Thanks, especially for that link to the help page on editing, that really spells it out in black and white. I probably should have looked there first, but wasn't thinking laterally enough to come at it from a "what should I do as an editor" POV.

Comment: If the edit content is a quotation from the link, it needs to be marked up as such and clearly attributed.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, I think the person who edited this should have posted as a new answer. It totally changes the character of the existing answer. This person put in the work and should get the credit. Not that a reviewer can do much about that...

Comment: Is there actually anything new in the answer though? It provides further explanation and references for the answer, but it doesn't add anything new that would justify it being a separate answer. Perhaps the content could have been commented below the post if you're worried it's changing the answer and author's intent too much, but I can't see how the added material would be correct to post as an answer.

Comment: It is the author's prerogative to edit an answer rather than post a new one if they wish primarily to just add some explanation and make an answer less sparse.